# Is there a way to monitor when a kernel module is having an error and execute an action accordingly?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, embedded-linux

---

Hey all,

We are working with a camera driver which is buggy (sometimes the frames are displayed with some artifacts) and this has nothing today with the hardware setup (cables are ok, cameras are ok, etc.).

However in the `dmesg` I can see that the camera module is printing some random errors. This problem can be fixed by rebooting the machine and the camera would behave normally again.

My idea is to monitor the errors printed by the camera module and execute some scripts accordingly ? (e.g. like stop acquiring from the camera if there's this error in the log, we also need to notify etc.). Is there some kind of udev rule where the action is `if_error` to do that? or any other tool for that matter ?

Bonus question: is there a way to monitor individual module's messages ? (i.e. not the dmesg | grep way).

Thanks.

Comment: `dmesg I can see that the camera` So monitor dmesg.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I'm not sure how reliable is that ? is it a "good practice" ?